# Creating one link for mobile app that redirect users according to the device they're using and sends UTM to play store and appstore

Tags: android, ios, mobile, google-play, utm

I've been trying to create a link for my mobile app that does the following:

1. redirects the clicker according to the device he clicked on (android to play-store, ios to AppStore and desktop to website)
2. enables UTM tracking in the Play-store and AppStore.

I succeeded doing each section seperatly but they don't seem to do both.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What we did for our product was, we made a link like for example:

https://example.com/app

When users click this link they will be taken to our webserver that checks what the user agent was and redirected the users to whatever link we like (in our case Google play or AppStore).

in that same check, you can also do your tracking requests.

Maybe this helps? :)